# Mysql Replica server's CPU utilization became high in EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, database-replication

I have an account in amazone. my primary MySql is a **large** instance. and i have other 2 **small** instances as replication servers. The hierarchy is Primary -> slave 1-> slave 2 . The problem is that some times the slave 1 and slave 2 showing high CPU utilization. We couldn't find out the exact reason. Slave 1 is act as a slave of primary and at the same time it act as Master of Slave 2. We searched a lot but we are still stucked as blind. 
Thanks in advance for all helps.

Comment: mysql replication method is rerun the CRUD inside slave server.  It is not a "direct data sync", imagine you have a high CRUD activities in master server.

Comment: Thanks my friend, i have an another doubt , Is the read operations  will rerun in the slave server?.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, when using MySQL native, asynchronous replication -- which is what RDS uses -- the replica servers need be as large as the master *or sometimes larger*.  The replicas receive "replication events" from the master, which may contain the actual queries that modified data -- insert, update, delete but not select -- this is "statement based replication" -- or may receive binary images of the rows added removed or changes on the master -- which is "row based replication."  By default, the master server decides, on a query-by-query basis, which format to use to send the replication events ("mixed").

In all cases `SELECT` statements are not sent to the replicas (except of course for `INSERT ... SELECT`), but they do need sufficient capacity to handled both the incoming changes from the master, as well as the `SELECT` queries that are run directly against the replica by your application.

In RDS for MySQL 5.6 and above,you can set the `binlog_format` to `ROW` to  force the master to always use row-based replication. This might improve your performance, and it might not -- it depends on the workload.  You cannot force RDS to use only "statement" mode, nor should you want to.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

In general, however, any time the replica is a machine with fewer resources than the master, the chance of replication lags increases.  The lag of the replicas can be monitored in Cloudwatch.

Comment: Thanks michael. i hopes that our problem is that our slaves are less configured than Master. i have one doubt also. how can we find that our slave is statement based replication or row based replication?